# $A$ and $D$ are in circumference of a circle and $B$ and $C$ are its inner points such that $PA$= $12$, $\frac{AB}{CD}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$. Find $PC$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, tangent-line

There is something misunderstanding with that question that I think it to have inadequte context or information (obviously for my little knowledge). So I couldn't solve the problem.

**SOURCE**: BANGLADESH MATH OLYMPIAD

> $PE$ is a tangent of the below diagram. The diameter of small circle is equal to the radius of the large circle and $BC$ is the diameter of the small circle. If $PA$ = $12$, $\frac{AB}{CD}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$, then what is the value of $PC$ ?

[image]

I denoted the center of small circle $H$ and drew three altitude lines $AG$, $HE$ and $DI$ from the vertices $A$ , $H$ and $DI$ and also denoted $AB$ = $x$ and $BH$ = $y$.

[image]

So, $HE$ = $y$. $\triangle AGP$ $\sim$ $\triangle HEP$ $\sim$ $\triangle DIP$. So, I showed the relation of $AG$ and $DI$ with $HI$ with the help of their proportion of length because of their similarity. But I was unable to show relation with the rest property and I couldn't find the value of $x$ and $y$.

I think I went into messed situation for solving the above problem. I don't think so even my used method is going to the right direction.

*It will be very helpful for me if someone please tells me in which way should I go or where is my mistake to find the right way. Thanks in advance*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $AB = x$ and $CD = 2x$

You can use the power of the point with respect to both circle and point $P$:

$$ PA\cdot PD (=PE^2)= PB\cdot PC$$ $$\implies 12(12+x+2r+2x)= (12+x)(12+x+2r)$$

so $$x+2r = 12\implies PC = 12+x+2r = 24$$

---

Note: Information about relation betwen both radius of the circles is irrelevant.

Comment: Why is it true your condition? I don’t understand

Comment: Do you know the power of the point? @FedericoFallucca

Comment: no sorry, I don’t know this concept

Comment: Google it or wiki

Comment: @greedoid You are absolutely right. The relation is totally irrelevant to the problem because I made the relation according to my own view and there was no description about the relation of radius and diameter of the small and the larger circle. I will try to notice the fact and I gave the information to provide some context. Pardon me for my fault.

Comment: I didn't know also about the conception of the power of the point. A few months ago, my math teacher taught me about this without its proof. As there is no existence about its theory in our textbook, so I couldn't memorise that theorem. Alas!